# Bedeutet "Fahrenheit" etwas außer einer Maßeinheit für Temperatur?

Tags: meaning

Ich bin Amerikaner/-in, aber ich wundere mich: hat "Fahrenheit" eine anderes Bedeutung, ausser einer Temperatur? Ich verstehe "Fahren" = "Drive", und "-heit" ist wie "-iness". Aber "Drive-ness" ergibt für mich keinen Sinn.

Comment: Es gibt schon eine Frage, die deine Frage beantworten sollte: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3296/does-the-word-fahrenheit-mean-anything-in-german

Comment: Thank you for correcting my German Christian Geiselmann!